# webview not displayed in api level 19

Tags: android, webview

In my `web-view` app, I have coded four activities each contains one `web-view`. All are running successfully but one of the activities is not displaying while running in emulator of api 19. There is no problem with lower versions.

It displays "165px" in the top left corner.

The code is given below:

```
package com.example.samworkshops;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Admin extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
final Activity activity = this;


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView4);
        webView.requestFocusFromTouch();

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://app.samworkshops.org/PasswordProtect.aspx");

        webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_admin);
            }
        });
        //webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ec1661"));
        webView.setInitialScale(95);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }


            @Override  
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('Button2').style.visibility = 'hidden';");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('Button2').style.display    = 'none'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt1').style.position = 'relative'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt1').style.right    = '225px'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt1').style.bottom    = '165px'  ;");

                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt2').style.position = 'relative'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt2').style.right    = '225px'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt2').style.bottom    = '165px'  ;");

                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt3').style.position = 'relative'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt3').style.right    = '225px'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt3').style.bottom    = '165px'  ;");

                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt4').style.position = 'relative'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt4').style.right    = '225px'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('atxt4').style.bottom    = '165px'  ;");

                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('txtUsername').style.position = 'relative'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('txtUsername').style.right    = '225px'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('txtUsername').style.bottom    = '165px'  ;");

                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('txtPassword').style.position = 'relative'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('txtPassword').style.right    = '225px'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('txtPassword').style.bottom    = '165px'  ;");

                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('DropDownList1').style.position = 'relative'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('DropDownList1').style.right    = '225px'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('DropDownList1').style.bottom    = '165px'  ;");


                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('Button3').style.position = 'relative'  ;");             
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('Button3').style.right    = '185px'  ;");
                builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('Button3').style.bottom    = '165px'  ;");




                view.loadUrl(builder.toString());
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);

            }  


        });

    }
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

activity_event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
/>
```

logcat

```
02-01 06:54:31.025: E/chromium(1436): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
02-01 06:54:31.035: E/chromium(1436): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
02-01 06:54:31.035: E/chromium(1436): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
02-01 06:54:31.035: E/chromium(1436): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
02-01 06:54:31.025: E/chromium(1436): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
```

Comment: Do you have the hardware GL acceleration enabled in the emulator?  Does it work on a physical device?  The OpenGL ES 2.0 support in the emulator may have some issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i discovered , wrap  your webchromeclient in an if statement, as it seems not to be compatible with kitkat. This solution worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
  This should work ,replace all "load url" with "evaluateJavascript" for API 19 



 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                        v.loadUrl(url);
                    } else {
                        v.evaluateJavascript(url,null);
                    }
```